# Java: Creating a GUI-Builder for Web app with custom tags

Tags: java, jsp, custom-controls, gui-builder, custom-tags

In our project we develop a framework that is meant to encapsulate most aspects of Java web development. My clients are other programmers who use this framework.

One of the things we encapsulate are JSP tags. We created custom tags for everything so that the user is not meant to use regular HTML and JavaScript at all.

Now I'm looking at ways to create a GUI-Builder for these custom tags. Meaning some sort of GUI application that allows the user to drag and drop graphic controls onto a canvas, and then based on that the application will generate the JSP code of the page.
Please note that our custom tags are not just for abstraction. Many of them are visible controls that consist of both HTML structures and JavaScript logic to control them. And the properties of the custom tag (that the user defines in the JSP) sometimes affect it's appearance and behavior.

If the tool can be a plugin for Eclipse it would be a huge bonus.

Is there any existing tool that allows to do that?

Is there a design pattern or best-practices tutorial for creating a tool like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Malki, I'm looking for something similar and I also need to build a webapp with it? Have you find a way to build a webapp project with an embedded GEF in it or some similar approach?

Answer (score 1):

I had worked on developing a tool similar to what you described. In our case we wanted a drag and drop GUI tool that would create RDBMS (Tables,Columns,RelationShips) like models for our server. We used eclipse GEF plugin for that.

GEF( Graphical Editing Framework) is a very mature framework that allows you to build a drag and drop graphical editor. You can create a Palette, define different shapes,associate different shapes  with different internal "models", define different kind of connectors, define what needs to be done when you drag and drop a shape in to editor etc..When I worked on it ,we build our tool as a normal eclipse plugin ( on top of GEF plugin) and deployed it on eclipse. Eclipse RCP framework was just getting started at that time.

http://www.eclipse.org/gef/

My experience is with GEF and I am pretty sure GEF will do your job. Once you download the demos and go through the code you will get an idea of what needs to be done to develop your own graphical editor.

There is another eclipse project called GMF (Graphical Modeling Framework).
GMF is built on top of GEF and EMF and  provides higher-level tools to build a graphical editor ,associate it with a source code editor ( you have the "Graphical View" on one tab,you have the "source view" on the other tab) etc. GMF is sort of a "higher-level" framework that manages the GEF plumbing code for you.

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/?project=gmf-tooling#gmf-tooling

Beware that both of the frameworks above will require some time and effort to understand. GEF is well documented. If you have had eclipse plugin development experience before thats a plus.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating an Eclipse plug-in, you're creating a multi-page editor.  One (or more) page(s) for the GUI, and one page for the resulting code.

When you first construct an Eclipse plug-in, one of the multi-page editors that you run across is the editor for the MANIFEST.MF file and the plugin.xml file.  This is a multi-page editor that produces two code files, rather than one.

The Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers will help you get an Eclipse plug-in started.

- Open Eclipse, and switch to the workspace you want to use to develop the plug-in.
- In the Eclipse menu bar, left click on File -> New -> Project...
- On the New Project dialog, open up the Plug-in Development folder, and left click on Plug-in Project.
- Left click on the Next button.
- On the Plug-in project dialog, give the project a name.  You can accept the defaults on the rest of the dialog.
- Left click on the Next button.
- Accept the defaults on the Content dialog, and left click the Next button.
- On the Templates dialog, left click on the "Plug-in with a multi-page editor".
- Left click on the Finish button.

The Eclipse javadoc is located in the Eclipse Help at Platform Plug-in Developer Guide -> Reference -> API Reference.

To help with understanding the Eclipse javadoc, you'll need a good tutorial.  The [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html) tutorial is pretty good.

If you have specific questions about your Eclipse plug-in, you can ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I realize that the whole point of the bounty is to draw attention to this question, but you didn't answer any of my questions. As I've stated, the "eclipse plugin" part is only a bonus. The main problem I'm facing is HOW to code a tool that does what I described. My main focus is to either find an existing framework that I can build upon, or find a design pattern or best practices tutorial for coding this kind of tool myself.

Comment: My answer describes how you get started.  You first have to decide on a platform and then you can talk about a framework.  Since you mentioned an Eclipse plug-in, that's where I started.  If you get a better answer, you can award that answer the bounty points.